# SQL backup loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I've built a backup query in SSMSE 2005 and saved as a text query.

Is there a way to loop through DB and write each as a unique file?

What I've done is copy/paste and find/replace database_name and run both in a single pass.  That works, but would like either:

Run a single loop script which backs up each DB individually OR 
Batch backup from the SSMSE GUI

```
BACKUP DATABASE [ION_Data_Nov08] TO DISK =
N'C:\Documents and Settings\DB.control\Desktop\ION Database Backups\121025_0700\ION_Data_Nov08'
WITH noformat, init, name = N'ION_Data_Nov08-Full Database Backup', skip,
norewind, nounload, stats = 10 

go

DECLARE @backupSetId AS INT 

SELECT @backupSetId = position
FROM   msdb..backupset
WHERE  database_name = N'ION_Data_Nov08' 
        AND backup_set_id = (SELECT Max(backup_set_id)
                             FROM   msdb..backupset
                            WHERE  database_name = N'ION_Data_Nov08')

 IF @backupSetId IS NULL
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR(
N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''ION_Data_Nov08'' not found.',
 16,1)
END

 RESTORE verifyonly FROM DISK =
  N'C:\Documents and Settings\DB.control\Desktop\ION Database Backups\121025_0700\ION_Data_Nov08'
 WITH FILE = @backupSetId, nounload, norewind

go
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/). It's free for versions less than 2012 and let's you easily run queries against multiple target databases.

*Disclaimer: I have no stake in this tool other than as a user of it for the last few years.*

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a script like this that includes a list of databases to process:

```
-- Houseclean.
set nocount on
if Object_Id( N'tempdb..#DatabasesToProcess' ) is not NULL
    drop table #DatabasesToProcess
go
declare @CurrentDateTime as DateTime = SysUTCDateTime()

-- We may wish to change the backup schedule:
--   Full backup daily.
--   Differential backup every two hours.  (12 per daily backup.)
--   Transaction log backup every 10 minutes.  (12 per differential backup.)
--   At most we should need to restore: most recent full backup, most recent differential backup, up to 12 log backups since the differential backup.

-- If this was a real emergency, we should attempt a tail-log backup to capture the last transactions from the ill database.
--   BACKUP LOG database_name TO backup_filename WITH NORECOVERY

-- NB: The compression option ("compression" or "no_compression") must be a keyword, variables are not supported.

-- Start with the list of databases to be managed and other configuration parameters.
--   IntervalSkew   lets us shift the backup cycle for each database so that we are not doing all of the full backups during the same interval.
declare @DatabaseNames as Table ( Name NVarChar(64), IntervalSkew Int )
insert into @DatabaseNames ( Name, IntervalSkew ) values
    ( N'master', 0 ), ( N'model', 0 ), ( N'msdb', 0 ), ( N'Foo', 1 ), ( N'FooElmah', 2 ), ( N'Bar', 0 )
-- Directory for the backup files.
declare @BackupDirectory as NVarChar(256) = 'C:\SQLServerBackups\'
-- Scheduled interval for this job.  We are assuming that we can get the backups done within this time.
--   NB: SQL Server Agent will not start a second instance of this job if the previous instance is still executing.
declare @MinutesPerInterval as Int = 10
-- Number of intervals between differential backups.  Two hours: 12 intervals * 10 minutes/interval.  Generates 12 differential backups/day.
declare @IntervalsPerDifferentialBackup as Int = 12
-- Number of intervals to shift daily operations from midnight UTC, e.g. 30 * 10 minutes/interval would cause the cycle to start at 05:00 UTC.
declare @IntervalOffset as Int = 30

-- It might be nice if we could use   msdb.dbo.sp_help_*   to confirm that we are scheduled to run at the correct interval.

-- Determine the backup type(s) for the current interval.
declare @CurrentDateTimeImprint as NVarChar(32) = Replace( Convert( NVarChar(19), @CurrentDateTime, 126 ), ':', '-' ) + 'Z' -- yyyy-mm-ddThh-mm-ssZ
declare @TimeOfDay as Time = @CurrentDateTime
declare @MinuteOfDay as Int = DatePart( hour, @TimeOfDay ) * 60 + DatePart( minute, @TimeOfDay )
declare @Interval as Int = ( @MinuteOfDay / @MinutesPerInterval - @IntervalOffset ) % ( 24 * 60 / @MinutesPerInterval )

print 'Pass started: ' + Convert( VarChar(23), @CurrentDateTime, 126 ) +
    ', Interval #: ' + Convert( VarChar(4), @Interval ) + ' (Offset ' + Convert( VarChar(4), @IntervalOffset ) + ')'

-- Get the metadata for the databases.
select d.name, d.recovery_model_desc, d.state_desc, drs.last_log_backup_lsn, DNs.IntervalSkew
    into #DatabasesToProcess
    from @DatabaseNames as DNs inner join
        sys.databases as d on d.name = DNs.Name inner join
        sys.database_recovery_status as drs on drs.database_id = d.database_id
declare @name as sysname
declare @recovery_model_desc as nvarchar(60) 
declare @state_desc as nvarchar(60)
declare @last_log_backup_lsn as numeric(25,0)
declare @IntervalSkew as Int

-- Process the databases.
declare @FullBackup as Bit
declare @DifferentialBackup as Bit
declare @LogBackup as Bit
declare @Database as NVarChar(128)
declare @BackupType as NVarChar(16)
declare @TargetFile as NVarChar(128)
declare DB cursor for
    select name, recovery_model_desc, state_desc, last_log_backup_lsn, IntervalSkew
        from #DatabasesToProcess
        order by name
open DB
fetch next from DB into @name, @recovery_model_desc, @state_desc, @last_log_backup_lsn, @IntervalSkew
while @@Fetch_Status = 0
    begin
    -- Process the database.
    set @Interval = ( @MinuteOfDay / @MinutesPerInterval - @IntervalOffset - @IntervalSkew ) % ( 24 * 60 / @MinutesPerInterval )
    set @FullBackup = case when @Interval = 0 then 1 else 0 end
    set @DifferentialBackup = case
        when @name = N'master' then 0 -- The   master   database does not support differential backups.
        when @Interval > 0 and @Interval % @IntervalsPerDifferentialBackup = 0 then 1
        else 0 end
    set @LogBackup = case
        when @recovery_model_desc = N'SIMPLE' then 0
        when @Interval % @IntervalsPerDifferentialBackup != 0 then 1
        else 0 end

    print '> Database: ' + @name + ', Recovery Model: ' + @recovery_model_desc + ', State: ' + @state_desc +
        ', Last Log LSN: ' + Coalesce( Convert( VarChar(32), @last_log_backup_lsn ), 'n/a' ) + ', Skew: ' + Convert( VarChar(4), @IntervalSkew ) +
        ', Adjusted Interval #: ' + Convert( VarChar(4), @Interval ) + 
        ', Full Backup: ' + case when @FullBackup = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end +
        ', Differential Backup: ' + case when @DifferentialBackup = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end +
        ', Log Backup: ' + case when @LogBackup = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO' end

    if @FullBackup = 1
        begin
        set @BackupType = 'FULL'
        set @TargetFile = @BackupDirectory + @name + '_' + @CurrentDateTimeImprint + '_' + @BackupType + '.bak'
        print '> > Backup Type: ' + @BackupType + ', Target File: ' + @TargetFile + ', Starting: ' + Convert( VarChar(23), SysUTCDateTime(), 126 ) + 'Z'
        backup database @name to disk = @TargetFile with init, skip, checksum, compression
        end

    if @DifferentialBackup = 1
        begin
        set @BackupType = 'DIFF'
        set @TargetFile = @BackupDirectory + @name + '_' + @CurrentDateTimeImprint + '_' + @BackupType + '.bak'
        print '> > Backup Type: ' + @BackupType + ', Target File: ' + @TargetFile + ', Starting: ' + Convert( VarChar(23), SysUTCDateTime(), 126 ) + 'Z'
        backup database @name to disk = @TargetFile with differential, init, skip, checksum, compression
        end

    if @LogBackup = 1
        begin
        set @BackupType = 'TLOG'
        set @TargetFile = @BackupDirectory + @name + '_' + @CurrentDateTimeImprint + '_' + @BackupType + '.bak'
        print '> > Backup Type: ' + @BackupType + ', Target File: ' + @TargetFile + ', Starting: ' + Convert( VarChar(23), SysUTCDateTime(), 126 ) + 'Z'
        begin try
            backup log @name to disk = @TargetFile with init, checksum
        end try
        begin catch
            print '> > ERROR: ' + Error_Message() + ' (' + Convert( VarChar(12), Error_Number() ) + ')'
        end catch
        end

    fetch next from DB into @name, @recovery_model_desc, @state_desc, @last_log_backup_lsn, @IntervalSkew
    end
close DB
deallocate DB
drop table #DatabasesToProcess

print 'Pass completed: ' + Convert( VarChar(23), SysUTCDateTime(), 126 ) + 'Z'
```